# Convert curl command to angular post http request

Tags: angular, api, http, curl

I don't know what I did wrong, I just want to convert this curl command to get work in angular post request.

Curl Command

```
curl -F file=@someFile.txt https://store1.gofile.io/uploadFile
```

Angular Service Method

```
url = "https://store1.gofile.io/uploadFile"
  getFile(file:File){
    return this.http.post(this.url,{
      params:{
        'file':file
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the file in as `data` and not in the params. If you have queryParams you can add them in the `options`.
This is the code you are looking for.
You dom't need options, this is just if you want to implement a upload progress bar/percentage.

```js
    const options = {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    }
    this.http.post('https://store1.gofile.io/uploadFile', file, options)
```

Comment: It shows an error - Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.

Comment: maybe you ned to add ` headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }),` to `options`.
Anyway it should work without just like this: `this.http.post('https://store1.gofile.io/uploadFile', file)`